# Searching area enclosed by a path

Tags: c#

I want to search areas enclosed by a complex path.

[image]

Input

```
var path = new []{new Point(X1,Y1),new Point(X2,Y2),new Point(X3,Y3),new Point(X4,Y4),new Point(X5,Y5)};
```

I want it.

```
(X2,Y2)-(X3,Y3)-(Xa,Ya)
(Xa,Ya)-(X4,Y4)-(Xb,Yb)
```

How do I search it?

Comment: Do you want to know if the points are actually on the path, that is if `(Xa, Ya)` is on the line segment of `{(X3,Y3),(X4,Y4)}`, or simply if the point is within the polygon that is created by the other points?

Comment: (Xa, Ya) and (Xb, Yb) are the intersection points of the input line.

Comment: So you want to find out if `(Xa, Ya)` and `(Xb, Yb)` are on a line segment and if those line segments intersect? The algorithm, or function you use depends on what you're trying to do...If you only care if the points are within the complex path (i.e. a polygon), you could use the `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath`; but needing to know specifically if the points are on the line segments _and_ if those line segments intersect is a different algorithm that you'd need to come up

Answer (score 0):

there's a few steps to what you are doing here. You need to:

1. Perform line intersections between each of the line segments to find where your intersection points are.
2. Create centroid points at the average of the Start point A, Start point B, Collision point, (and then for each permutation of Start Point [A, B], end point [A, B] and collision point.
3. Perform a dotproduct or point in tris check to verify that your centroid point is inside a triangle and if so:
4. Calculate the area of the Tri using the standard area in triangle formula (I think it's 1/2 base times height off the top of my head)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this approach in a few steps:

1. Break the lines where they meet other lines and create a new list of lines (or paths)
2. Eliminate lines with one free end (if a line doesn't meet another one at the start or the end)
3. Start from one point and go through lines to the other points and try to find the correct route back to the start point (if you pass a duplicate point, the route is wrong)
4. Save newly found closed route
5. Eliminate all points that are inside the newly found area and connected lines
6. Eliminate all points with just two connected lines and also these two lines
7. Eliminate all lines that their center point is inside the newly found area
8. Go to step 3 until there left no line in the list
9. Now you have a list of enclosed areas

**Note:** you can easily find a good approach for the calculation of the intersection point of two lines, the area of the enclosed part, the center point of a line, and Checking that a point is inside an area

Best wishes,